# Не заливается сайт на хостинг и выбивает ошибку "не удается получить доступ к сайту"

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, hosting

База данных подключается, все хорошо, но появляется ошибка  "не удается получить доступ к сайту". Хотя на локальном сервере все хорошо отрабатывает, базу правильно переношу но не могу понять из-за чего это может быть[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Правильно - это как?

Comment: В файле wp-config ввожу имя базы данных, имя пользователя и пароль. (localhost уже стоит). В phpMyAdmin импортирую базу данных, которую сразу экспортировал из локального phpMyAdmin

Comment: [Как правильно переносить сайт на WordPress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress#answer-767562)

Comment: Для начала настрой домен на хостинге, а потом переноси как написано по ссылке выше